# CMSIS-RTOS osMessageGet function

Tags: c, rtos, cmsis

I have been working on a software based on CMSIS-RTOS and I have a problem with
function osMessageGet. My software consists of four RTOS tasks and two of them
exchange data via osMessageQueue in conjunction with osPool. One task (Task_100ms) is a producer and second task (Task_200ms) is a consumer.

Task_100ms receives data from CAN bus and creates structures containing the received data. The producer allocates memory on pool (flash_pool) using function osPoolAlloc and receives pointer to allocated memory. Producer copies the content of exchanged structure onto the memory block in pool using this pointer and puts copy of this pointer onto the queue (flash_queue) using function osMessagePut (please see the *put_program_chunk* function code below).

Task_200ms tries to retrieve the pointers from flash_queue using osMessageGet function (please see the *program_chunk* function code below). As long as the queue is empty consumer waits and everything is OK. Then a first pointer is put onto flash_queue by Task_100ms. Task_200ms calls osMessageGet function and this results in uC reset in case the timeout for osMessageGet is set to osWaitForever. In case the timeout for osMessageGet is set to 0 software reset isn't invoked. But in both cases (timeout equal 0 or osWaitForever) when I step through the code in Eclipse I am not able to achieve the immediately following statement after osMessageGet function call.

Can anybody give me any advice where a cause of my problems could be? I can send 
you whole source code if it is needed. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

```
    BOOL put_program_chunk(main_controller_req_t req){

    main_controller_req_t *p_req;

    BOOL retval;
    BOOL no_memory = FALSE;

    /*!!!*/
    osStatus status;
    uint8_t tmp;

    // allocate memory in pool
    p_req = (main_controller_req_t *)osPoolAlloc(flash_pool);

    if(p_blk == NULL){
        printf("No more space in flash pool.\r\n");
    }


    if(p_req != NULL){
        *p_req = req;

        // insert the prepared request into the transmission queue
        // put the message into the queue
        // wait 5 ms?
        status = osMessagePut(flash_queue, (uint32_t)(p_req), 5);
            /*!!!*/
            if(status == osOK){
                tmp = 1;
            }else{
                tmp = 0;
            }
    }else{
        no_memory = TRUE;
    }


    if(no_memory){
        retval = FALSE;
    }else{
        retval = TRUE;
    }

    return retval;

}

void program_chunk(void){

    osEvent event;
    osStatus status;
    main_controller_req_t *p_req;
    main_controller_req_t req;
    pdt_result_t result;

    // !!!
    uint8_t tmp;

    // retrieve the data block from the message queue
    event = osMessageGet(flash_queue, 0);

    // !!!
    tmp++;

    /*
    if(event.status == osEventMessage){
            p_req = ((main_controller_req_t *)(event.value.p));

            // copy the content of memory block in receiving pool
            req = *p_req;

            // free the memory in pool
            status = osPoolFree(flash_pool, p_req);

            // Normal (=000000) or Boot (=BOOTBL) mode?
            if(*req.mode == 0 && *(req.mode + 1) == 0 && *(req.mode + 2) == 0 &&
              *(req.mode + 3) == 0 && *(req.mode + 4) == 0 && *(req.mode + 5) == 0){

            // Normal mode

            // program chunk for the Slot_0 or Slot_1?
            if(((req.flash_page_number >= 0x01) && (req.flash_page_number < MAX_AC_PAGE)) ||
               ((req.flash_page_number == MAX_AC_PAGE) && (req.flash_block_number <= MAX_AC_BLOCK))){

#ifdef APP_DEBUG
                                        printf("AC programming!\r\n");
#endif
                    // yes - program the retrieved program chunk
                    result = pdt_app_program_chunk(req.data_block, 32);

                    // according to the result send the short flash write response message - page and block OK
                    send_short_flash_load_write_resp((result == PDT_RESULT_OK) ? TRUE : FALSE, FALSE, req.flash_page_number, req.flash_block_number);

                    // if unsuccessful programming
                    if(result != PDT_RESULT_OK){
                        // go into WAIT_TO_FLASH_LOAD_COMPLETE
                        SetLogicSignal(LGoWtFlshLdCmpl);
                    }

            // program chunk for Motor Controller?
            }else if(((req.flash_page_number == MAX_AC_PAGE) && (req.flash_block_number > MAX_AC_BLOCK && req.flash_block_number <= MAX_MC_BLOCK)) ||
                    ((req.flash_page_number > MAX_AC_PAGE) && (req.flash_page_number <= MAX_MC_PAGE))){

#ifdef APP_DEBUG
                                        printf("MC programming!\r\n");
#endif

                    // yes - program the retrieved program chunk
                    result = pdt_mc_update_internal_motor_controller_chunk(req.data_block, 32);

                    // according to the result send the short flash write response message - page and block OK
                    send_short_flash_load_write_resp((result == PDT_RESULT_OK) ? TRUE : FALSE, FALSE, req.flash_page_number, req.flash_block_number);

                    // end of the binary?
                    if((req.flash_page_number == NO_PAGES) && (req.flash_block_number == BLOCKS_IN_PAGE) && result == PDT_RESULT_OK){

                        result = pdt_mc_update_motor_controller();
                        // invoke SW reset
                        result = pdt_app_switch_application();

                    // if unsuccessful programming
                    }else if(result != PDT_RESULT_OK){
                        // go into WAIT_TO_FLASH_LOAD_COMPLETE
                        SetLogicSignal(LGoWtFlshLdCmpl);
                    }

            // wrong destination address?
            }else{

#ifdef APP_DEBUG
                                        printf("Wrong destination address!\r\n");
#endif

                    // wrong data block destination
                    send_short_flash_load_write_resp(FALSE, TRUE, req.flash_page_number, req.flash_block_number);

                    // go into WAIT_TO_FLASH_LOAD_COMPLETE
                    SetLogicSignal(LGoWtFlshLdCmpl);
            }

        }
    }
    */
}
```

Comment: You have any simple code to show? Did you check CMSIS docs?

Comment: I have just added the code snippets. Yes, I have checked the CMSIS docs.